# How to show sql result on server console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

In **Rails v2.3** , **Ruby 1.8**, if I run a **sql statement** with following code in my model class:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from cars;")
```

**How can I show the query result in server console?**

I tried :

```
rslt = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from cars;")
p rslt
```

but it only returns me "MySQL result object" on the server console, not the exact result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are couple ways to get mysql "answer" from your query. you can call each and it will iterate over each row (just one row - count in your case). take a look at [mysql gem docs](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mysql/2.8.1/frames) to see other available methods such as each_hash and all_hashes.

```
rslt = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from cars;")
rslt.each {|mysql_result| puts mysql_result}
```

Comment: you can use .all_hashes

Answer (score 8):

You can just use the `to_a` method on your result, like so:

```
result = connection.execute(sql)
result.to_a
```

This will return (and show if in console) what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the environment you are using currently. For development the default logger level is *debug*, for production it's *info* level. You can use it this way:

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  def index
    rslt = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select count(*) from cars;")
    logger.info "#{rslt}"
  end
end
```

You can read more about rails logging on Mike Naberezny's blog: http://mikenaberezny.com/2007/02/24/rails-logging-tips/

Comment: Rails logger doesnt output to server console, it outputs to the log file. Also logger.info "#{rslt}" will log "MySQL result object" in the log, no matter what log level is set.

Comment: Yes, I meant a rails logging.